# How to add an additional Sound track to an existing Video

Tags: video

I have a MP4 and MKV video file which also has its own Audio track. I want to add an additional track to it to cover another language for it, what Terminal or GUI way is there available to insert and sync a MP3 file to the already existing video so that:

- The video shows 2 audio tracks (The existing one and the new one am inserting)
- Optionally the video shows the name of the tracks
- I can sync the new audio with the video
- I do not replace the existing audio with the new one
- Maintain the same video quality as before
  (It is a 1080p video with very high details. Do not want to mess with this since it takes way too long to get it right)

This would help in, for example, adding additional language sound tracks to an existing video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**MKV ONLY**

**mkvmerge GUI** from **mkvtoolnix-gui** package.

[image]

- Click **add** to select the video and audio files you want to merge.
- In the **Tracks, chapters and tags:** box, select the new audio track (from the audio file you added), then you will be able to set its language (under **General track options** tab) and delay (under **Format specific options** tab).
- Set the **Output filename**, then click **Start muxing** to save the video file.

You can also remove tracks and set the default audio track.

Comment: You know I had the tool but did not use it to this point. Thanks Eric.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Sometimes I use avidemux, but I couldn't manage to save files with more than one audio track. It isn't as powerful as [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) but it's very handy.

Comment: Works like a charm with MKV files!

Answer (score 11):

For now this is what I have found (Still looking for the MKV way of doing it):

**MP4 ONLY**

You would need to first install `gpac` package:

```
sudo apt-get install gpac
```

Now proceed with the following command:

```
MP4Box -new -add OriginalMovie.mp4 -add Track2.mp3#audio:delay=300 Output.mp4
```

Where

- `MP4Box` is the command to do this and yes it is capitalized
- The first `-new` will tell MP4Box a new file will be created. You could put this at the end like "-new Output.mp4" but I wanted to put it in the beginning.
- The first `-add` is to add the Original video file.
- The second `-add` is to add the new track which I called Track2.mp3. It can have any other name.
- The part that has the `#audio:delay=300` is to tell MP4Box that this specific new track I am adding is an audio track and I need to add a Delay of 300 ms.

This way I can add the original video, insert a new track and even control the sync. The best part is, since MP4Box does not touch the video quality, it only takes a couple of seconds to add the Track, so I can test very quickly if the Audio delay is perfect or not.

Just in case, I extracted the sound from the other language like this:

```
avconv -i "AnotherSoundFile.mp4" Language.mp3
```

This would give me the mp3 sound track of that file and then I insert it to another file like I mentioned above.

Comment: Works! Just works!

Comment: To extract you can also use `MP4Box -raw 2 inputFile.mp4` which will extract second track (usually audio track) from inputFile.mp4. To check which track is which, use `MP4Box -info inputFile.mp4` and to get some more info about precise track use `MP4Box -info 2 inputFile.mp4`

Answer (score 2):

**BOTH MKV and MP4**

Just try using **avconv** (same as ffmpeg)

```
avconv -i FIRST_INPUT_FILE -i SECOND_INPUT_FILE -c copy -map 0:v:1 -map 1:a:12 OUTPUT_FILE
```

**-i INPUT_FILE** input file - may be almost any file (video and audio)

**-c copy** copies tracks to output without re-encoding them (fastest)

**-map 0:v:1 -map 1:a:12** copies 2nd video track from 1st file AND 13th audio track from 2nd file

( **0**(input file)**:v**(video tracks)**:1**(second track) )

Example:

```
avconv -i MY_MOVIE_3D.mp4 -i MY_MOVIE_WITH_DUBBING.avi -c copy -map 0 -map 1:a:0 OUTPUT_MOVIE.mp4
```

This command copies **ALL** tracks form **MY_MOVIE_3D.mp4** AND **1st** **audio** track from **2nd** input file - **MY_MOVIE_WITH_DUBBING.avi** - into **OUTPUT_MOVIE.mp4**

Answer (score 1):

you can use Yamb for editing mp4, which is like mkvmerge GUI but then for mp4box

or you can use MACHETE to edit MP4 files using a GUI to add / replace audio
can also edit the video with it and edit other formats like MKV with it but its not free
it costs $19.00